# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition + SQL Server 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition (Academic) come with SQL Server 2008 developer edition? (VS 2008 came with ss 2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional) and [SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/Developer.aspx) are separate products, and it depends on the installation package you choose whether it includes SQL Server 2008.

If it does not, you can get SQL 2008 Developer at the given link, and use it for testing and development.

> SQL Server 2008 Developer includes all
>   of the functionality of Enterprise
>   Edition, but is licensed only for
>   development, test, and demo use. The
>   license for SQL Server 2008 Developer
>   entitles one developer to use the
>   software on as many systems as
>   necessary.

Comment: I just asked the question because VS 2008 came with SQL server 2005 dev. edition. Can I dowload SQL 2008 Developer edition then?

Comment: My VS 2008 came with SQL 2008 express, so it does depend on the setup used. In your case yes, download the developer edition from the link. If you don't need any specific 2008 features, you can also just use 2005.

Comment: Also note that Developer is the same as Enterprise, licensed for dev only. Enterprise includes clustering and such high-end management tools, which you won't need unless you're studying for those, or building a massively huge system.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide the aforementioned link?

Comment: @csetzkorn the link is in my answer, the one that reads "SQL Server 2008"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all versions of Visual Studio from Express upwards come with the option to install SQL Server Express. However, in addition (or instead of) You can install whatever version you want.